# How to fill a gridLayout 8x8 with Random images

Tags: java, android

I was developing a kind of "Candy Crush" and what I need is that when you open the app, the elements (gems) are randomly generated.
In the xml I created an 8x8 "GridLayout" that will store 6 ImageView, where each ImageView is a gem. What I was thinking about doing is that from the .java in some way through an 8x8 matrix, I am loading the elements randomly to my GridLayout. But I just would not know how to do it. If you help me, I would greatly appreciate it,  I have been stuck in this for 2 days. Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int [] vector = new int[]{R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.green,R.drawable.yellow,R.drawable.red,R.drawable.purple,R.drawable.orange};
private int num=6;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int matriz[][] = new int[8][8];

    GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    int numOfCol = grid.getColumnCount();
    int numOfRow =  grid.getRowCount();


    for (int x = 0; x <= numOfCol; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= numOfRow; y++) {
            int numero = (int) (Math.random() * num) + 1;
            grid.addView(grid, matriz[x][y]);
        }
    }



<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:columnCount="8"
android:rowCount="8"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#053b13"
android:id="@+id/grid"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:src="@drawable/blue"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/green"
    android:src="@drawable/green"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/orange"
    android:src="@drawable/orange"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/purple"
    android:src="@drawable/purple"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/yellow"
    android:src="@drawable/yellow"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">

</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/red"
    android:src="@drawable/red"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:onClick="gemas">

</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for(int c=0; i<grid.getChildCount();i++){
    int bg = vector[ rnd.nextInt(vector.length) ];

    grid.getChildAt(c).setBackgroundResource(bg);
}
```

---

Note: I wrote it in Kotlin and Java code is from memory. If you find errors, drop a comment.

Kotlin code:

```
val vector = intArrayOf(
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round
)

for (c in 0 until grid.childCount) {

    grid.getChildAt(c).backgroundResource = vector[Random.nextInt(vector.size)]

}
```

Result

[image: 3x3 grid]

Comment: Thanks for answer Doc. But that I need is to do a reference to my GridLayout. I thought to use a matrix 8 x 8, like the code I posted.The code that you comment, inside the for its okay,but I think that the for is wrong.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. You have a gridlayout in xml. Then what is the problem?

Comment: i'll post my output

Comment: the icons in the grid are at random position. emulator screenshot.

Comment: Okay thanks, one question. Do you find an error in my xml?

Comment: 8x8 imageview in xml? better make it in code rather than xml. Here is a 3*3 grid xml https://pastebin.com/F1N39Bw9 for the output shown in code

Comment: Thanks Doc for help me

Comment: No. I sure did not.